# How to define a path of motion for the camera in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

*EDIT: I CHANGED THE QUESTION WHEN I REALIZED THAT I ACTUALLY NEEDED TO MOVE THE CAMERA AND NOT THE POLYGON. MY BAD, EVERYONE.*

So I'm taking a class on OpenGL and need to define a path that the camera can automatically traverse.

**How can I make my camera move around my world by hitting the F1 key?**

*Just to clarify,
I know how to use keyboard functions that use constants such as GLUT_KEY_F1.*

I'm trying something new and am clueless. 
Is this as simple as incrementing (with a loop) the values in the parameters of gluLookAt() ?

Here is the code that I have now:

```
   if(key == GLUT_KEY_F1)
   {
        float x;
        collisionKey = GLUT_KEY_F1;
        for(x = 0.0; x < 3600.0;)
        {
           x += .01;
           gluLookAt(200 + x, cameraY, 400 + cameraZ, 200 + studentX, 250 + studentY, studentZ, 0, 1, 0);
        }
 }


glutPostRedisplay();
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I have a question, what is the problem ?

Comment: Do you need smooth paths (e.g. Bezier curves or cubic splines) or just lots of straight lines?

Comment: @Nick Bradford so those for loops are not making much sense. What exactly is the question ?

Comment: About the only thing I can tell you from looking at your code is that the second loop is a waste of time. You can run that loop 1 time or a million times and the end result will be no different.

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah honestly, it doesn't matter to me (just whichever is easier), as long as the polygon moves along the path automatically.  I feel like this works, it just doesn't redraw the world or something after it finishes. My world just goes blank when this code finishes running.

Comment: @blackmesa I need a polygon (which is drawn with the method: studentCode()) to move on it's own through my world (800x800). I believe I have it working, but whenever this code finishes running the world goes blank.  **How can I get the world to remain displayed after the code finishes running?**      Let me know if this isn't clear! Thanks

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman because I'm not calling glTranslatef() after current = .1; or because I forgot to add the '+' for the '+=' ?

Comment: Because you are assinging the same value to `currentX` over and over.